# Batch file to edit multiple files in a directory

Tags: batch-file

I want to edit files in a directory ending with .xml extension. I have written code to edit one file :

```
@echo off
echo Removing...
for /f "skip=17 delims=*" %%a in (C:\xml\file1.xml) do (
echo %%a >>C:\newfile.xml
) >nul
echo Lines removed, rebuilding file...
xcopy C:\newfile.xml C:\file.xml /y >nul
echo File rebuilt, removing temporary files
del C:\newfile.xml /f /q >nul
msg * Done!
exit >nul
```

I would like to edit all the files in a directory.

Answer (score 1):

Just doing what you have asked:

```
@echo off
for %%F in ("C:\xml\*.xml") do (
  echo Processing %%F
  echo Removing...
  for /f "skip=17 delims=*" %%a in ("%%F") do (
    echo %%a >>C:\newfile.xml
  ) >nul
  echo Lines removed, rebuilding file...
  xcopy C:\newfile.xml "%%F" /y >nul
  echo File rebuilt, removing temporary files
  del C:\newfile.xml /f /q >nul
  msg * Done!
  echo(
)
exit >nul
```

But I believe you wanted `"delims="` (no delimiters) or `"tokens=*"` (all tokens), not `"delims=*"` (break at *).

Also, the code can be greatly simplified and be made much more efficient:

```
@echo off
for %%F in ("C:\xml\*.xml") do (
  >"%%F.new" (for /f "skip=17 delims=" %%a in ("%%F") do echo %%a)
  move /y "%%F.new" "%%F" >nul
  echo %%F
)
msg * Done!
exit /b
```

Even faster, use MORE as long as you don't need to preserve TAB characters, and the files aren't too big (at some point, redirected MORE hangs waiting for a keypress when processing large files).

```
@echo off
for %%F in ("C:\xml\*.xml") do (
  more +17 "%%F" >"%%F.new"
  move /y "%%F.new" "%%F" >nul
  echo %%F
)
msg * Done!
exit /b
```